# Determine which process is locking the clipboard

Tags: c#, .net

I have a peculiar error where some process occasionally appears to be using the clipboard when my application goes to handle copy & paste operations.  There are some retry work arounds, and I have an acceptable solution in place, but I would like to locate which process it is if the error occurs again.

Comment: While I agree with the sentiment of this question, what exactly would you do with this information? Even if this were possible (and, I'm not sure it is), there's not a lot you could do with the answer. (Kill the process? Not a chance!)

Comment: @mike Might you put up a message to let the user know? It could be a process under the user's direct control.

Comment: @mickeyf Even if you do that, what am I, the user, supposed to do? _I_ didn't lock the clipboard, and there's nothing at all I can do to unlock it, short of closing whatever program is locking it (and, since I'm trying to get my work done, you can just forget about that.)

Comment: @Mike: It's simply a step in the diagnosis.  If it's an application on a user's machine that we can either remove or update, then that takes care of the entire thing.  Rather than program around some other process, I'd prefer to tackle the root cause and not worry about it again.

Comment: @Richard, you should add your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I've wrapped my solution into an easy-to-use method (and some declarations):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr GetOpenClipboardWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out int lpdwProcessId);

private static Process GetProcessLockingClipboard()
{
    int processId;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetOpenClipboardWindow(), out processId);

    return Process.GetProcessById(processId);
}
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Is there a way to block the clipboard knowingly to see how this all works out ?

Answer (score 5):

Based on Jeff Roe's answer, but shows how to get the text length, so could be > 500. Also handles case where window is not found.

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetOpenClipboardWindow();

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int GetWindowText(int hwnd, StringBuilder text, int count);

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int GetWindowTextLength(int hwnd);

private static string GetOpenClipboardWindowText()
{
    var hwnd = GetOpenClipboardWindow();
    if (hwnd == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        return "Unknown";
    }
    var int32Handle = hwnd.ToInt32();
    var len = GetWindowTextLength(int32Handle);
    var sb = new StringBuilder(len);
    GetWindowText(int32Handle, sb, len);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a similar solution, but this gives you a string you can show the user:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetOpenClipboardWindow();

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int GetWindowText(int hwnd, StringBuilder text, int count);

private string getOpenClipboardWindowText()
{
    IntPtr hwnd = GetOpenClipboardWindow();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(501);
    GetWindowText(hwnd.ToInt32(), sb, 500);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for the process name, but that's potentially more useful for end users.

Answer (score 0):

To diagnose something like this I would suggest starting with Process Explorer, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653

Comment: Thanks, but neither I nor the users have time to monitor something like that.  Anyways, I found what I was looking for.

Comment: @RichardPianka: If you found what you were looking for, do share it here. SO is a two way street.

Answer (score 0):

The following question on SuperUser has several possible solutions:
https://superuser.com/questions/145268/copy-paste-stops-working-on-windows-7

What worked for me was downloading the `GetOpenClipboardWindow.zip` tool which allowed me to find the program which was locking the clipboard (VirtualBox).