# Problems with clipboard in C#

Tags: c#, exception, clipboard

I used to write a *lot* of Visual Basic 6.0, and recently I've dabbled in VB.NET.  I've been working with a startup friend of mine on some general bits of programming, and found that C# is pretty straightforward.

The application I've written works fine 99% of the time, but occasionally, I can't write to the clipboard without the application crashing out to the "Windows has detected a problem".

This is what was in the Event Log:

```
Application: SLicenseTool.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
Stack:
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32, IntPtr)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32, IntPtr)
   at System.Windows.Clipboard.Flush()
   at System.Windows.Clipboard.CriticalSetDataObject(System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.Clipboard.SetDataInternal(System.String, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Clipboard.SetText(System.String, System.Windows.TextDataFormat)
   at System.Windows.Clipboard.SetText(System.String)
   at SLicenseTool.MainWindow.GenerateLicense_Click(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonUpThunk(System.Object, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(System.Delegate, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, System.Windows.RoutedEvent)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(System.Object, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(System.Delegate, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(System.Windows.Input.InputEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(System.Windows.Input.InputReport)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr, System.Windows.Input.InputMode, Int32, System.Windows.Input.RawMouseActions, Int32, Int32, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr, MS.Internal.Interop.WindowMessage, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at SLicenseTool.App.Main()
```

I'm using the [rhino-licensing](https://github.com/ayende/rhino-licensing/) library.

This is the code that is in GenerateLicense_Click:

```
var license = generator.Generate(txtName.Text, id, expirationDate, attribs, licenseType);
Clipboard.SetText(license);
```

What I'm not sure about is why it would work on my PC, and a few times on my friend's PC, but it randomly fails. It seems that there's some problem accessing the clipboard, but I'm unsure what the next steps are with debugging/ fixing it.

I'm going to rewrite the application to stop using the clipboard, and instead use regular save file / open file dialogs. It seems more reliable.

Comment: clipboard is not reliable for saving data... anything can remove it...

Comment: Oh, I don't really care about the data.. It's really just a dumping ground for the app.  It'd be nice to know why it doesn't work, though.

Comment: Pretty much any time you're saving data to the clipboard it should be available elsewhere; putting it in the clipboard should just be a convenience mechanism.

Comment: It also uses File.WriteAllText(blah, text), but the clipboard thing should make it easier..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930219/how-to-handle-blocked-clipboard-and-other-oddities might help...

Comment: @Don That is the dodgiest thing ever. Totally abandoning the clipboard now. Sod it.