# Windows 7 clipboard copy paste operation using C#

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I'm working on a Windows application where I need to use clipboard data. I am trying to copy text from clipboard by the code below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace MultiValuedClipBoard
{
    class Class1
    {

        public String SwapClipboardHtmlText(String replacementHtmlText)
        {
            String returnHtmlText = "hello";
            if (Clipboard.ContainsText(TextDataFormat.Html))
            {
                returnHtmlText = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Html);
                Clipboard.SetText(replacementHtmlText, TextDataFormat.Html);
            }
            return returnHtmlText;
        }
    }
}
```

Calling the above function by:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Media;

namespace MultiValuedClipBoard
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Class1 aas = new Class1();
            string a = aas.SwapClipboardHtmlText("chetan");
            Console.WriteLine(a);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

When running this code it gives the output "Hello" which is the default value, not clipboard data.

Comment: Well, it would depend on what's in your clipboard, right? Are you sure there is HTML (specifically, data of type HTML) in your clipboard?

Comment: I tried above code with  TextDataFormat.text also but it doesn't work when clipboard had some text .

Comment: Can you try Clipboard.ContainsText() instead?

Comment: yeah i can try but it doesn't help me out .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly `Clipboard.ContainsText(TextDataFormat.Html)` evaluates to `false`. Which means that the clipboard in fact does not contain text in the format you specify.

I changed your program to prove the point:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Clipboard.SetText("boo yah!", TextDataFormat.Html);
    Class1 aas = new Class1();
    string a = aas.SwapClipboardHtmlText("chetan");
    Console.WriteLine(a);
    Console.WriteLine(Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Html));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Output:

```
boo yah!
chetan
```

Comment: your code works fine but whenever i tried to copy anything from windows clipboard without SetText() it returns null and before this i copied some text in clipboard . My App runs thread which automatically copy content from windows clipboard .

Comment: I don't know what that means.

Comment: I need whenever i copy some text with cntrl+c i can retrieve that with Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.text) is it possible ???

Comment: yeah i also think so but it doesn't . Try above code without Clipboard.SetText("boo yah!", TextDataFormat.Html); . You will feel like me.

Comment: No, you are quite wrong. If the clipboard contains `TextDataFormat.Html` then it will be returned. You code is telling you that the clipboard does not contain `TextDataFormat.Html`. It is accurate when it does so. Read the first paragraph of my answer once more. That describes what is happening.

Comment: Finally i m done with my question thanks for making me correct .

Answer (score 2):

Your code will not work because of two reasons:

[1] When you say:

`if (Clipboard.ContainsText(TextDataFormat.Html))`

Here you are basically assuming that the clipboard already contains a text and that too in HTML format, but depending on the values you are setting in the clipboard it doesn't look like you are intending to use the pre-existing clipboard value anywhere in your program. So, this if condition should not be there.

[2] Secondly, you are further trying to set the string "chetan" to the clipboard which is definitely not in HTML format. So,

```
            Clipboard.SetText(replacementHtmlText, TextDataFormat.Html);
```

becomes

```
            Clipboard.SetText(replacementHtmlText, TextDataFormat.Text);
```

---

Hence, effectively, your new code becomes something like this:

```
        String returnHtmlText = "hello";
        //if (Clipboard.ContainsText(TextDataFormat.Html))
        //{
            returnHtmlText = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text);
            Clipboard.SetText(replacementHtmlText, TextDataFormat.Text);
        //}
        return returnHtmlText;
```

Comment: i tried code suggested by you . But Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text) returns null . It means clipboard doesn't have any value but i copied text before running this app .

Comment: Sometimes you run into problems related to blocked clipboards, as some other application might be keeping the clipboard locked. See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930219/how-to-handle-blocked-clipboard-and-other-oddities

Comment: It could also be an issue with your Windows-7 securities/permissions. Try this on an XP machine if you have one.

Comment: Thanx yeri for your valuable info but don't we have any solution for windows 7  ....

Comment: Try adding the [STAThread] attribute above your main function. See second-last answer in this SO thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518701/clipboard-gettext-returns-null-empty-string