# Having exception with Clipboard while using Inputsimulator

Tags: c#, wpf

My project is about text processing software and using [InputSimulator library](https://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#README.md).

When my program simulate Ctrl+C and get text from clipboard, It gave an exception like this.

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in     PresentationCore.dll

Additional information: OpenClipboard Failed (Exception from HRESULT:0x800401D0 (CLIPBRD_E_CANT_OPEN))
```

[here's](https://www.sendspace.com/file/1mb6i0) my project and here's my code

```
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000); // wait for opening notepad and type any text to test
        while (true)
        {
            string oldclipboard = Clipboard.GetText();
            InputSimulator input = new InputSimulator();
            input.Keyboard.ModifiedKeyStroke(VirtualKeyCode.CONTROL, VirtualKeyCode.VK_A); // select text

            input.Keyboard.ModifiedKeyStroke(VirtualKeyCode.CONTROL, VirtualKeyCode.VK_C);
            string highlightedtext = Clipboard.GetText();
            //do sth.(text processing)
            input.Keyboard.ModifiedKeyStroke(VirtualKeyCode.CONTROL, VirtualKeyCode.VK_V);
        }
```

I'm sure that it is about conflict between the library and clipboard.
but I don't know what is the problem.

So, Why it is throwing an exception? and Is there any alternative way to to this?

Thanks

P.S. I've also try "Sendkeys.Sendwait". It didn't give any exception but it is unstable.

Comment: Please copy your exception in your answer instead of linking externally.

Comment: Please show code and error inline as text in the post.

Comment: There is a solution very close to what you need here: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/205820/How-can-I-use-Csharp-Clipboard-to-get-selected-tex

Comment: I don't want to use sendkeys because sometimes it won't send a keystroke and unstable even I've try this.<appSettings>

<add key="SendKeys" value="SendInput"/>

</appSettings>

Comment: I've tried your example and it looks like you're calling clipboard functions to often. If I add `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);` before end of `while(true)` statement, error does not occur. You should probably catch exception and retry if it fails.

Comment: Could be that your library or another program is blocking the clipboard. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930219/how-to-handle-blocked-clipboard-and-other-oddities

Comment: @bidy I found that Notepad is blocking clipboard. So I've try "while (GetOpenClipboardWindow() != IntPtr.Zero)" It won't exit the loop and my program was freeze. I've also try Closeclipboard win32api but result is the same.

Comment: @Jure It's real time program so it's can't be wait. When I use sendkeys, I don't have to delay to do things with clipboard.